# Asp.Net Core - Custom Authorization and Identity from another server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm trying to figure out how to configure/use the Asp.Net Core Authorization with the credentials and user data in another server, accessed through an API.

For example, in the "Auth" server, we have the Auth database, that stores users, roles and claims. Some examples:

GET https://auth.myserver.com/v1/users/4/IsInRole/Admin

The response is a simple bool.

Or:

GET https://auth.myserver.com/v1/users/4/GetRolesForUser/

The response is a list of roles.

The another server is the resource server (also entirely API based, no front-end). It stores a lot of data that demands authorization by roles and claims.

Also, we have a third player: the client.

The **client** will:

1. Ask the **auth** server to get a bearer and a refresh token, using an username and a password
2. The **client** stores those tokens and send the bearer to the **resource** server to get some data
3. The **resource** server will ask the **auth** server if the bearer token is valid
4. If it is, then the resource server needs to ask the **auth** server again about the user that has that bearer token, and if that user has the necessary holes/claims that are necessary to access the requested resource.

The 4 step is my doubt. I imagine that should happen on the resource server controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]   //API CALL HERE TO THE AUTH SERVER (?)
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData()
{
    ...
```

Basically, I don't know **how to Authenticate an user on the context (just until the request is returned), putting it in the HttpContext.User, using my own custom validation process**.

I've tried to simplify this architecture as much as possible to make my question more clear. Please forget about the security on the "Auth" server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jwts this flow can be simplified roles can be stored in claims which means that no api call is needed in the authorise attribute.

Also the resource server doesn't need to verify that the token is valid that can be done using a secret.

Look into thinktecture the following are good resources https://leastprivilege.com/ and https://brockallen.com/